# SCCM 2007 - How to save modification on SMS_CollectionRuleQuery QueryExpression

Tags: c#, sccm

I need to implement application to add devicename to Query Expression on rule SMS_CollectionRuleQuery and save it by using SCCM 2007 SDK. I expect that Put() method must be use to save query expression but it appear that modification is not save !

What is the good way to save it ?

Thank you

Philippe.

**Snippet code :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine;
using Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider;
using System.Management;

public class SCCM_Try_Change_QueryExpression
{
    public static void RunSnippet()
    {
        // Connect on SCCM 2007
        SmsNamedValuesDictionary namedValues = new SmsNamedValuesDictionary();
        WqlConnectionManager connection = new WqlConnectionManager(namedValues);
        connection.Connect("blabla", "blabla", "blabla");

        // Get collection CS10001E
        IResultObject collection = connection.GetInstance((@"SMS_Collection.CollectionID='CS10001E'"));

        // Get Rules
        ManagementBaseObject smsCollection = (ManagementBaseObject) collection["CollectionRules"].ObjectArrayValue [0];
        WL ("Rule Type="+smsCollection.ClassPath.ClassName);
        WL ("\nOriginal Query="+smsCollection["QueryExpression"].ToString ());

        // Change query : add devicename XXXXX
        string newQuery = smsCollection["QueryExpression"].ToString ().Replace (" ( \""," ( \"XXXXX\",\"");
        smsCollection.SetPropertyValue("QueryExpression", newQuery);
        WL ("\nNew Query="+smsCollection["QueryExpression"].ToString ());

        // Save change
        collection.Put();               

    }

}
```

**Application Output :**

```
Rule Type=SMS_CollectionRuleQuery

Original Query=select <...> from SMS_R_System where Name in ( "D07CAU" ) order by Name

New Query=select <...> from SMS_R_System where Name in ( "XXXXX","D07CAU" ) order by Name

Press any key to continue...
```

**WHEN I RESTART APPLICATION, Original query not include my new device name "XXXXX"**

```
Original Query=select <...> from SMS_R_System where Name in ( "D07CAU" ) order by Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the collection rules are not merely fields of the SMS_Collection object, you'll probably have to accomplish your goal by by deleting the offending rule (`DeleteMembershipRule`), and adding a new one with the updated query (`AddMembershipRule`).